# Is KViews a spelling mistake?

Tags: bug, spelling

The whole thing is weird really, because I haven't been on this site for a vast period of time and have never seen anything like this before.

So, I was browsing the interesting section of questions when I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/how-do-i-enumerate-an-enum). It looks something like [image]

As you can see, it has a very large amount of votes, but that's not what is unusual. The typo I mentioned is the `views`, which they apparently wrote as `kviews`. I found this odd as why would this question be any different than any other question, so why does it have the typo?

Anyway, I thought you guys should know so you can fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its perfect, nothing wrong in  this

this is how its work

1k means 1000
151 kviews == 151k views == 151000 views

Comment: You learn something every day. I'll accept in about 11 or so minutes.

Comment: Its weird, I thought everyone knew this stuff but in college a guy asked what `@` meant? in relation to a per item, $ each..

Comment: I think most people understand #k to mean "thousands", but printing a number and then underneath that the the label "kviews" does not necessarily cause that connection to be made, because it is outside the pattern of numerals immediately followed (with no space) by "k". Anyway, I guess I just wanted to say I too thought it was a spelling mistake or signified some unique view at first.

Comment: I find it confusing too. If the text said ``151k views`` then I would have understood it right away.